# Exception while accessing StoreAccount from Redemption Outlook library

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am trying to access the FreeBusyList from account configured in Outlook and using the Redemption dll. We are using Redemption dll in .Net to test the Outlook data.
Code snippet:

```cs
RDOStores stores = OutlookRedemption.Instance.rdoSession.Stores; 
RDOFreeBusyRange list = stores.DefaultStore.StoreAccount.CurrentUser.FreeBusyList;
Getting below exception:
    System.InvalidCastException : Error in IMsgServiceAdmin::AdminProviders: MAPI_E_INTERFACE_NOT_SUPPORTED
    at Redemption.RDOStoreClass.get_StoreAccount()
    Client\Calendar\MeetingRequests\FreeBusy\CreateMeetingRequest.cs(193,0): at clientTests.Client.Calendar.MeetingRequests.FreeBusy.CreateMeetingRequest.CreateMeetingRequest_ZimbraFreeBusy_01()
---- UNHANDLED EXCEPTION ----
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is raised since you are most likely using Outlook's existing session by setting `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` to `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` from OOM in a process other than outlook.exe, and MAPI profile management API has marshaling bugs that prevent the `IMsgServiceAdmin` and other profile interfaces from working correctly across process boundaries.

The good news is that you don't need that call: `stores.DefaultStore.StoreAccount.CurrentUser` is equivalent to just  `rdoSession.CurrentUser`.